# Client tries to go to Login.aspx after throwing exception in IdentityServer4 client OIDC middleware

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 as an authentication server and an ASP.NET MVC client with it.  If I throw an exception in the oidc middleware:

```
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
                        IdentityServerHost + "/connect/token",
                        clientIdent,
                        secret);

                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);
                    throw new Exception("Something bad happened"); //I will put this in an if checking for tokenResponse.IsError, forcing it right now.
```

Then instead of getting that exception from Global.asax's Application_Error() method on this line:

```
Exception ec = Server.GetLastError();
```

I get the following exception there:  {"The controller for path '/login.aspx' was not found or does not implement IController."}

I'm not sure why it's suddenly trying to fall back to what I think is Windows / forms authentication or how to turn that off.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've tried adding autoFormsAuthentication="false" and enableSimpleMembership="false" keys to the appSettings section of web.config, didn't help.  Also tried to have it ignore any routes containing aspx in the app startup RouteConfig, in that case it just returns that the login.aspx file wasn't found.

Comment: I found this page:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5/
The client does create an authentication ticket (got initial code from MVC Owin Hybrid client sample), so it's using forms auth.

Comment: I found that if I add this section to web.config, that it will bypass that error and I'll end up with the error from the owin middleware (which is what I wanted) in Global.asax (essentially, the MVC Owin Hybrid client at least uses forms authentication, creating an authentication ticket).  By adding this to web.config, when the middleware fails, I think it uses the forms auth to go back to the page it was on before the middleware triggered / the exception gets to the right place):
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/myPage" name="cookies"></forms>
</authentication>

Comment: Part of this question was a result of me being relatively ignorant of error handling in MVC.  As a result, I was switching between ErrorHandlerAttritbute and using Global.asax, and stepping on myself.  That in addition to the errors not always reaching Global.asax due to the above.  I also triggered an infinite loop by placing [HandleError] over the error controller method instead of over the method that would generate the error (newbie mistake).  In the end, I stopped using HandleErrorAttribute.  I still don't know how to match error types in IdentityServer with it.

Comment: Another problem was that in Global.asax, I was trying to use Server.Transfer, and for some reason that wasn't working at all.  Server.TransferRequest works for me however.